# How to optimize this FFmpeg command to avoid server crash?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I'm running FFmpeg version 6.0.1 in Amazon Linux AMI 2023. I'm trying to concat multiple images from S3 bucket with different size and output it as mp4 using this command:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -f concat -safe 0 -i demux_file.txt -filter_complex "scale=1344:768:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1344:768:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 18 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart -shortest -map 0 -y output.mp4
```

If my input images has large resolution the server freeze and I need to restart it. I'm planning to add audio on it but it seems I dont have enough resources anymore.

What I have done to isolate the case:

- Tried using smaller resolution input images
- Removed the scale filter

And it works fine. Is there any other way to optimize this and avoid server crash? or do I need to upgrade? I only have 1GB Memory in my server.